# How to Capture Multiple Text Blocks

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file, file content is as

```
FileBegin=20151001
Begin=0001-Testing-1
End=0001-Testing-1
Begin=0002-Testing-2
End=0002-Testing-2
Begin=0003-Testing-3
End=0003-Testing-3
FileEnd=20151001
```

I want return the array of text block via regex using c#, the array result have three items as:

> Begin=0001-Testing-1
>   End=0001-Testing-1
>
> Begin=0002-Testing-2
>   End=0002-Testing-2
>
> Begin=0003-Testing-3
>   End=0003-Testing-3

How the regex to write for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the matches (You need to use multiline flag):

```
^Begin(.|\n)*?End.*$
```

See [sample](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5EBegin(.%7C%5Cn)*%3FEnd.*%24&i=FileBegin%3D20151001%0D%0ABegin%3D0001-Testing-1%0D%0AEnd%3D0001-Testing-1%0D%0ABegin%3D0002-Testing-2%0D%0AEnd%3D0002-Testing-2%0D%0ABegin%3D0003-Testing-3%0D%0AEnd%3D0003-Testing-3%0D%0AFileEnd%3D20151001&o=m)

Answer (score 0):

```
\bBegin[\s\S]*?\bEnd\b.*
```

You can simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/36